# WebLogic Transaction Manager

Tags: java, weblogic, xa

Anyone knows what do I have to change so that WebLogic Transaction manager works with a cluster ? I tested and I have it working by now with one server. How can I run it on a cluster ?

InterposedTransactionManager itm = TxHelper.getClientInterposedTransactionManager(initialCtx, serverName);

Is the second parameter I do believe needs to be changed !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That is the correct call - [from the documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11035_01/wls100/javadocs/weblogic/transaction/TxHelper.html):

*If the initial context is obtained from a non-clustered server, then the server name specified should refer to the same server. If the initial context is obtained from a cluster, then the server name specified should refer to a server within the cluster.*

Just pick any server in your cluster and it should still work the same way.

You will probably want to look into other options if you are clustering such as [(Oracle API here)](http://docs.oracle.com/middleware/1212/wls/WLAPI/weblogic/transaction/InterposedTransactionManager.html):

```
setClusterwideRecoveryEnabled(boolean isClusterwideRecoveryEnabled)
```

*Specifies whether recovery operations for a distributed transaction are applied to all the servers of the cluster hosting InterposedTransactionManager rather than just the server hosting the InterposedTransactionManager.*